# Prevent two divs from executing the same function jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

HTML

```
<div>
    <div class="change"></div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="change"></div>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$('div').click(function(){
    $('.change').css('background','red');
});
```

I want to click the upper div and change the background of the upper div, but it change both. I know I can make classes and stuff, but what if I have 100 divs like that? I don't want to create a class and a jquery statement for each one!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Within the event listener, `this` refers to the clicked element, therefore you could use:

```
$('.change').click(function(){
    $(this).css('background','red');
});
```

Comment: But I want to make it when I click the div, so can I use 

`$('div').click(function(){
    $(this).children().css('background','red');
});`

?

Comment: @pedritoalfonso Yep, or you could use `.find()`, or you could even use a context selector, `$('.change', this).css('background','red')`... http://jsfiddle.net/whzL6w17/

Comment: how is that different to what pedritoalfonso explained? .change does pick up your individual div when you click on it, hence the "click" event.